# How to recover a router password?

Tags: router

I have a TP-LINK Router and I would like to know how to recover it password because I have lost it ? I would like to access to the configuration window but It seems I forgot the password

Comment: It might be easiest for you to reset the router entirely using a reset button as this will restore default configurations. Very few routers have backdoors in them that are public and they are being patched all the time - trying to "recover" it is likely futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot recover router password with no access to the Router setup.

You must do a hardware reset of the router to factory specifications.

This will reset your router to the initial user name and default password for your router. Check your specific router documentation.

Any router we have reset to factory does this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to hard reset it and use the default password that the device provides.
Search for your router model "hard reset" or "factory defaults" and "deafult password".